# Cisco Prime Infrastructure : How to access the database?

Tags: cisco

I'm currently working on Cisco Prime Infrastructure 2.2 and I'm having trouble making my own template.

I'm actually trying to access the interfaces "Description" data from the Cisco Prime database but even after a while looking at the official Cisco documentation and forum topics, I can't find the info.

I want to set my own DB variable in the CLITemplateDbVariablesQuery.properties file but before I need to "explore" the existing tables in order to find the field I need. Is there a way to get the **database schema** ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

SSH into Prime and run 'root'. (You might need to enter 'root_enable" as a precursory task.

See here for more detils:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/prime_infrastructure/3-0/command/reference/cli30/cli211_appendix_011.html#wp8104678890

Now you can view the linux shell.

Enter 'cd /opt/CSCOlumos/conf/ifm/template/inventoryTagsInTemplate'
then 'ls'

Hey presto you can see the 'CLITemplateDbVariablesQuery.properties' file is here

From here you can type 'more CLITemplateDbVariablesQuery.properties' to view the contents of the file.  :)